# Redirect stdout to a Jinja variable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, stdout

I would like to redirect `sys.stdout` to a Jinja variable so that I can see it in the frontend (I'm using Flask server). How do I do this? Is there a better way to get the stdout to the HTML template?

This is what I have tried:

```
sys.stdout = jinja2.Template("<div id='console'>{{ console }}</div>")
```

But I get this error when using `print`:

```
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'write'
Exception ignored in: <Template memory:b4a2a9f0>
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

I've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python), but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you would like to do you should write something similar (then adjust it according to your needs):

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

import jinja2
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/test")
def home():
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
    print("test")
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    return jinja2.Template("<div id='console'>my output = {{ console }}</div>").render(
        console=mystdout.getvalue()
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 80, True)
```